# upload web worker with javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-worker

Can anyone give me source code of javascript for an upload function using a javascript webworker? i searched everywhere and couldnt find a good solution.
I did find though a couple of usefull links on how to use web workers and why is it usefull [this one for example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

I could pass the uploaded file from the main page to the worker file, how what i want to do is to pass it again to the php file that would upload it to the database automatically, so let me rephrase my question then, how can i pass a javascript variable to php file?

Comment: All you would need to do is do an ajax post request and attach the data you want to upload, I would have thought

Comment: can you explain in details a bit more please?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I could pass the uploaded file from the main page to the worker file, how what i want to do is to pass it again to the php file that would upload it to the database automatically, so let me rephrase my question then, how can i pass a javascript variable to php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a javascript variable to a php file by using an ajax request:

```
​var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest​(),
    params = "param1=" + escape(data) + "&param2=" + escape(data2);

​ajax.open("POST", "myphpfile.php", true);
ajax.send(params);
```

Where `data1` and `data2` contain the stuff you want to send to the php file. You can add as many parameters as you like, but remember that the `&` sign will be interpreted as the end or a parameter and onto the next one. That is why we escape the data before sending it.

Note:ajax requests do work in web workers, as far as I know

On the server side, you can access the data by reading the `$_POST` array:

```
echo(rawurldecode($_POST['param1']));
```

Replace `param1` with the name of the variable that you have sent via the javascript. We use `rawurldecode(string);` to unescape the data at the other end.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: that was so helpfull thank you so much =)) sorry for my bad questions as well, im new to stackover flow =)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow then! I'm glad I could help. Next time it might be a good idea to search existing questions before asking :)